# Getting "Cannot access a disposed context instance." error while writing just one unit test. Others working fine

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am getting this error below while writing unit tests in a C# .net core project:

> System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
> Object name: 'DbContext'.

`DbContext` is configured as a scoped service while, the DAL is a transient service. The unit tests for the other methods are working fine but I am facing this issue only for one method.

This is the unit test class:

```
public class AnimalDataAccessTests
{
    private Mock<IServiceProvider> _mockServiceProvider;
    private Mock<ILoggingService<AnimalRetentionDataAccess>> _mockLogger;

    private AnimalRetentionDataAccess _animalRetentionDataAccess;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mockServiceProvider = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();
        _mockLogger = new Mock<ILoggingService<AnimalRetentionDataAccess>>();

        var dbContext = GetDatabaseContext();

        _mockServiceProvider.Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(dbContext)))
             .Returns(dbContext);

        var serviceScope = new Mock<IServiceScope>();
        serviceScope.Setup(x => x.ServiceProvider)
            .Returns(_mockServiceProvider.Object);

        var serviceScopeFactory = new Mock<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        serviceScopeFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateScope())
            .Returns(serviceScope.Object);

        _mockServiceProvider.Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory)))
            .Returns(serviceScopeFactory.Object);

        IConfiguration configuration =
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json")
                   .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                   .Build();

        _animalRetentionDataAccess = new AnimalRetentionDataAccess(_mockServiceProvider.Object, configuration, _mockLogger.Object);
    }

    private static DbContext GetDatabaseContext()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<dbContext>()
                               .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                               .Options;

        var databaseContext = new dbContext(options);
        databaseContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (!databaseContext.Animal.Any()) 
        {
            databaseContext.Animal.Add(
                 new Animal() { AnimalId = "testAnimalId",
                                AnimalName = "testAnimalName",
                                AnimalSuffix = "testSuffix",
                                AnimalBirthTime = DateTime.Now,
                                AnimalRetention = 36,
                                IsAnimalRetentionEnabled = true });
        }

        databaseContext.SaveChanges();

        return databaseContext;
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task UpdateAnimalDataSuccess()
    {
        var animal = new Animal 
                         {
                             AnimalId = "testAnimalId",
                             AnimalName = "testAnimalName",
                             AnimalSuffix = "testSuffix", 
                             AnimalBirthTime = DateTime.Now,
                             AnimalRetention = 36,        
                             IsAnimalRetentionEnabled = true
                         };

        var maxLastOpenedDate = DateTime.Now;

        var result = await _animalDataAccess.UpdateRecord(50, true, animal);
    }
}
```

The method implementation is :

```
public async Task<Animal> UpdateRecord(double animalRetention, bool isAnimalRetention,
        Animal refresh)
    {
        using var scope = _provider.CreateScope();
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<dbContext>();

        var updateRecord = dbContext.Animal.FirstOrDefault(x =>
            x.AnimalId == animal.AnimalId && x.AnimalName == animal.AnimalName);

        if (updateRecord != null)
        {
            updateRecord.AnimalRetention = (int)animalRetention;
            updateRecord.IsAnimalRetention = isAnimalRetention;
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return updateRecord;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The `DbContext` is defined as follows:

```
public partial class DbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbContext()
    {
    }

    public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Animal> Animal { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.AnimalId });
            entity.HasKey(e => new {e.AnimalName});
            entity.Property(e => e.AnimalId).HasMaxLength(100).IsUnicode(false).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.AnimalName).HasMaxLength(100).IsUnicode(false).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.AnimalSuffix).HasMaxLength(100).IsUnicode(false).IsRequired();           
            entity.Property(e => e.AnimalBirthTime).HasColumnType("datetime").IsRequired();           
            entity.Property(e => e.AnimalRetention).HasColumnType("int");
            entity.Property(e => e.IsAnimalRetentionEnabled).HasColumnType("bit").HasDefaultValue(false);
        });
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Can I please get help on this?

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for the edits. Can you please suggest some solution to the issue?

Comment: I am not sure, thus only a comment. You should try to put `var dbContext = GetDatabaseContext();` as a class field. It runs out of scope after the Setup method has finished executing, which is before your actual test starts.

Comment: @Marcel: I tried it, but its not resolving the issue.